# Best approach to handle loading state in react when using Redux toolkit and react query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-query

I'm building a React application with react query and Redux toolkit and i'm wondering how Can i handle loading state ?
What's the best approach ?
Should i create ann appSlice which has loading in his state or should I handle it with useQuery hook isLoading prop ? I'm confused because when i use asynThunk there is pending state , now when I'm using react query there is also isLoading

Comment: i would take a look at rtk-query which comes with redux toolkit: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview

Answer (score 0):

Use react query to manage/load/update the server state and redux with redux toolkit to manage/update the front end state.

You should dispatch the actions on onSuccess() callbacks of useQuery hook to update/load/sync the front-end state with server state.

You can show a spinner or something while the isLoading is true.

Hope this helps.